# Imaging a Macbook

Tags: mac, mac-osx, imaging

I have a system in place to reimage MacBooks, but I'm looking to automate it.

Right now I have a USB Drive that is booting to the Mac OSX Install Disc 1 and from there I am running the asr command from the terminal.

My goal is to have a ISO that when burned to CD will boot a mac and pull the image (In DMG format) down to the disk over the network.

We have the network setup for this, all I need is a CD to do this.

Anyone have any experience to share on this topic or some good links to get me going in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the netboot functionality of MacOS Server and [DeployStudio](http://www.deploystudio.com) to image and deploy images to our Macs. Works great.

I believe you can config a linux server to proved Netboot services if you don't have a Mac Serrver

Comment: OS X server cost some, but it may pay off handsomely if you need to do this many many times.

Answer (score -1):

I have no experience with this but you might look into the netboot/netimage functionality of MacOS Server, maybe this can help you.

Beside that, another idea I have would be to look into (Pure)Darwin as a system for the boot disk, which might be capable of run asr and which you can likely can configure like a normal Linux/Unix distribution. Again, this is just an idea.